# Apache and Active Directory authentication

Tags: apache-2.2, active-directory, ldap

I'm having trouble with LDAP authentication in Apache 2.2. Here's the excerpt from httpd.conf

```
<Location /folder>
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Project"
   AuthBasicProvider ldap
   AuthLDAPBindDN "user@domain"
   AuthLDAPBindPassword "my_password"
   AuthLDAPURL "ldap://my_domain_controller/?samAccountName?sub?(objectClass=user)"
   Require valid-user
</Location>
```

I keep getting "ldap_search_ext_s() for user failed" in error.log. I tried using my quoted DN as AuthLDAPBindDN but results were the same. What could be the problem?

Comment: After some research, some posts indicate that adding "AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off" might work.

Comment: No, it doesn't change anything

Comment: have you tried querying the AD directly with this filter and attributes ? (ldapsearch)

Answer (score 1):

When I had this problem, it was apparently because Active Directory was returning referrals, and the openldap libraries couldn't cope.  Two different solutions work for me; I prefer the second.  First solution: in /etc/openldap/ldap.conf put the line

```
REFERRALS no
```

That, of course, assumes you're using the openldap libraries; I don't have recent experience with any others.

Second solution: the Active Directory Global Catalog service does not generate referrals, so point your ldap at its port instead of the normal port (of course, you'll need to be talking to a Global Catalog server; to find them look at the output of "dig -t srv _gc._tcp.domain", where "domain" is your domain).  The port for the global catalog is 3268, so

```
AuthLDAPURL "ldap://my_domain_controller:3268/?samAccountName?sub?(objectClass=user)"
```